# Place a Button in ListCtrl - wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

Is is possible to place a button inside of a ListCtrl item with wxPython? Right now I have a ListCtrl that has data with a file name and size, and I want the user to be able to click a button, to download the file. If this isn't possible, is there a way to display an image in the ListCtrl, and then make it clickable so that I can bind an action to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You will have to use "[UltimateListControl](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/UltimateListCtrl.html)", a generic list implementation that can attach any kind of widget to rows. Check its demo files for examples. 
You're probably best off [grabbing the trunk code](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/viewvc/wx/wxPython/3rdParty/AGW/agw/ultimatelistctrl.py?view=log) for bugfixes and other changes - I'm not sure how often Andrea updates the main zip on his site

I've yet to use the control, but its demo is very impressive.