# Adding a button to every row in ListCtrl WxPython

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, listctrl

I want to add a radio button / Normal button for every row in ListControl.

Can anyone provide some useful hints in doing that ?

So, the basic functionality I want to achieve is like this.

Against every item added in the list, I want to add a valid / invalid flag which will be populated by user. So every row will have one radio button.

Any information in this regard will be helpful

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595913/place-a-button-in-listctrl-wxpython?rq=1) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not supported by the ListCtrl. You can add a checkbox via the CheckListCtrlMixin though. Otherwise, you'll have to use the UltimateListCtrl, which is pure Python and allows all kinds of widgets to be added to it. You can see how it works if you download the wxPython demo and look in the Advanced Generic Widgets section of the demo. This little tutorial might also help you get up and running: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/02/wxpython-an-intro-to-the-ultimatelistctrl/