# Radio button display and selection issue in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am creating  multi-column lists which are all equal in length and also generating number of radio buttons equal to the length of list. I have couple of issues:

1] Display issue: In following fig., I get radio buttons. 
[image]

But when I scroll down this is what happens. [image]

Following is a snippet of my code to generate it Please assist me to fix this issue so that I get full list of radio buttons displayed properly.

```
w = 0
for i in range(1,len(lut_code)):
    w += 30
    rb_G = wx.RadioButton(scroll1, -1, "G", (500,w), style=wx.RB_GROUP)
    rb_F = wx.RadioButton(scroll1, -1, "F", (540,w))
    rb_P = wx.RadioButton(scroll1, -1, "P", (580,w))
```

2] Selection of radio button: When I want to select a single radio button from a row, a complete row is selected instead and it gets blue in color like in following fig. [image]

Is it because of my use of wx.ListCtrl to display these columns? What would be the fix or alternative method to only select radio button of choice instead of selecting whole row?

Comment: When the radio button turns blue can you select any of the options?

Comment: No, it just turns complete row into blue bar.

Comment: How did you insert the radio buttons inside list_ctrl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time to figure this out. I think you are actually drawing the radio buttons on the frame by specifying the position! This will obviously not work in this case because your listCtrl comes to the foreground when you try to select a radio button.

If you notice the radio buttons are not correctly aligned according to the list items. The gap between the buttons is greater than the gap between rows of the list.

The problem with using list_ctrl is you cannot put widgets like radio buttons in them.

I would suggest you to use something like wx.ScrolledWindow for this. Put each row into a sizer and stack these sizers vertically.

UPDATE:

```
import wx

class Frame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Test", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( -1,-1 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        sizer0 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.scrolledWindow = wx.ScrolledWindow( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL )
        self.scrolledWindow.SetScrollRate( 5, 5 )
        grid_sizer = wx.GridSizer( 0, 8, 0, 0 )

        self.head1 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"Code", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.head1.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.head1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head2 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"Classification", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.head2.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.head2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head3 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"A", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.head3.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.head3, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head4 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"B", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.head4.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.head4, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head5 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"C", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.head5.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.head5, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head6 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"D", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.head6.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.head6, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head7 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"Cond.", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.head7.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.head7, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head8 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"Update", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.head8.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.head8, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.column11 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"86", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.column11.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.column11, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.column12 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"Urban", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.column12.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.column12, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.column13 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"68", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.column13.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.column13, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.column14 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"80", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.column14.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.column14, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.column15 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"86", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.column15.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.column15, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.column16 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, u"89", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.column16.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.column16, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.column17 = wx.StaticText( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.column17.Wrap( -1 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.column17, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        radio1Choices = [ u"G", u"P", u"F" ]
        self.radio1 = wx.RadioBox( self.scrolledWindow, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, radio1Choices, 3, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS )
        self.radio1.SetSelection( 0 )
        grid_sizer.Add( self.radio1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.scrolledWindow.SetSizer( grid_sizer )
        self.scrolledWindow.Layout()
        grid_sizer.Fit( self.scrolledWindow )
        sizer0.Add( self.scrolledWindow, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

        # Bind the radio box select event to a function
        self.radio1.Bind( wx.EVT_RADIOBOX, self.on_selected )


        self.SetSizer( sizer0 )
        self.Layout()
        self.Maximize()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        self.Show()

    def on_selected(self, event):
        # Depending upon the option selected the values of A,B,C,D are changed
        if  self.radio1.GetStringSelection() == 'P': 
            self.column13.SetLabel('25')
            self.column14.SetLabel('27')
            self.column15.SetLabel('34')
            self.column16.SetLabel('12')
        elif self.radio1.GetStringSelection() == 'F':
            self.column13.SetLabel('56')
            self.column14.SetLabel('70')
            self.column15.SetLabel('49')
            self.column16.SetLabel('54')
        else:
            self.column13.SetLabel('78')
            self.column14.SetLabel('83')
            self.column15.SetLabel('69')
            self.column16.SetLabel('100')


if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.App()
        Frame(None)
        app.MainLoop()
```

I wrote this sample code to show you how you can do it. It's a bit crude but I hope you get the picture.

You might also want to check the answer in this post:[Adding a button to every row in ListCtrl WxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466244/adding-a-button-to-every-row-in-listctrl-wxpython). It might be a better choice.

Comment: I don't fully understand with your explanation of `wx.ScrolledWindow`. Is there any example you can point me to?

Comment: Your answer is useful but I have to update columns 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D' whenever I change selection from 'G' to 'F' or 'P' for all classification types. I think I can't read these columns as static text because it has to be dynamic. Do you suggest any way to make selection of radiobutton dynamic to show change of values in these four columns?

Comment: You can bind the radio_button selection event to a function that checks which option is selected and updates the columns accordingly

Comment: Oh I thought with use of static text I can't change values. Do you have or know of any demo which does this function of updating static text values?

Comment: Nice. It works as I require. Now I have to read complete lists as Static Text and generate same number of radio buttons as number of rows. Then index all radio buttons to update corresponding row values on selection.