# Grid sizer static text edit

Tags: wxpython

I have `grid_sizer` for 7 columns with more than 10 rows in a split window. All row values are inserted through lists in the form of static text. I want to change static text of a row whose radio button I click. I am able to get it done for single row from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575810/radio-button-display-and-selection-issue-in-wxpython/24578503?noredirect=1#comment38344304_24578503). Now I want to edit static text of for example row number 7. Any suggestions on how to set label of specific row with grid sizer?

```
import wx
# I have these lists from a text file: lut_code, lut_type, 
#  lut_A, lut_B, lut_C, lut_D, condition2
lut_code = ['10', '11', '12', '13']
lut_type = ['Urban', 'Low Density Residential', 'Medium Density Residential', 'High Density Residential']
lut_A = ['61', '54', '61', '77']
lut_B = ['75', '70', '75', '85']
lut_C = ['83', '80', '83', '90']
lut_D = ['87', '85', '87', '92']

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "test", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(900, 600))
        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)
        scroll1 = wx.ScrolledWindow(splitter, -1)
        scroll1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        scroll1.SetScrollRate(5,5)
        self.grid_sizer = wx.GridSizer( 0, 8, 0, 0 )

        self.head1 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, u"Code", (15,2))
        self.head1.Wrap( -1 )
        self.grid_sizer.Add( self.head1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head2 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, u"Classification", (80,2))
        self.head2.Wrap( -1 )
        self.grid_sizer.Add( self.head2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head3 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, u"A", (270,2))
        self.head3.Wrap( -1 )
        self.grid_sizer.Add( self.head3, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head4 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, u"B",(320,2))
        self.head4.Wrap( -1 )
        self.grid_sizer.Add( self.head4, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head5 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, u"C", (370,2))
        self.head5.Wrap( -1 )
        self.grid_sizer.Add( self.head5, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head6 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, u"D", (420,2))
        self.head6.Wrap( -1 )
        self.grid_sizer.Add( self.head6, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head7 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, u"Cond.", (470,2))
        self.head7.Wrap( -1 )
        self.grid_sizer.Add( self.head7, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.head8 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, u"Update", (565,2))
        self.head8.Wrap( -1 )
        self.grid_sizer.Add( self.head8, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        # specified headers (code, class, A, B, C, D, cond., update, condition2) using static text and grid sizer

        v = 0
        for lu,t,a,b,c,d,cond in zip(lut_code,lut_type,lut_A,lut_B,lut_C,lut_D,condition2):
            v += 39
            self.column11 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, str(lu), (15,v))
            self.column11.Wrap( -1 )
            self.grid_sizer.Add( self.column11, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            self.column12 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, str(t), (80,v))
            self.column12.Wrap( -1 )
            self.grid_sizer.Add( self.column12, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            self.column13 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, str(a), (270,v))
            self.column13.Wrap( -1 )
            self.grid_sizer.Add( self.column13, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            self.column14 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, str(b), (320,v))
            self.column14.Wrap( -1 )
            self.grid_sizer.Add( self.column14, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            self.column15 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, str(c), (370,v))
            self.column15.Wrap( -1 )
            self.grid_sizer.Add( self.column15, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            self.column16 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, str(d), (420,v))
            self.column16.Wrap( -1 )
            self.grid_sizer.Add( self.column16, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            self.column17 = wx.StaticText(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, str(cond), (480,v))
            self.column17.Wrap( -1 )
            self.grid_sizer.Add( self.column17, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        # I have added radiobuttons as follows using "rb_list" (which I created using length of "lut_code")

        rb_list = [20]
        r = 18
        for i in range(1,len(lut_code)):
            r += 39
            rb_list.append(r)

        radio1Choices = ['G','F','P']     
        self.radiobuttonlist = []
        for i in rb_list:
            self.radiobuttonlist.append(wx.RadioBox(scroll1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, (550,i), (30,5), radio1Choices, 3, wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS | wx.NO_BORDER))
            self.radiobuttonlist[-1].SetSelection(2)
            self.radiobuttonlist[-1].my_identity = i                                                                                        
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_RADIOBOX,self.Getvalues,id=self.radiobuttonlist[-1].GetId())
            self.grid_sizer.Add(self.radiobuttonlist[-1], 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        # added buttons in scroll2
        wx.StaticText(scroll2, -1,message, (15,150))
        splitter.SplitVertically(scroll1,scroll2,-220)

        self.btnCancel = wx.Button(scroll2, label="Cancel and Close", pos=(50,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, id = self.btnCancel.GetId())

        self.btnCancel = wx.Button(scroll2, label="Update and Close", pos=(50,80))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, id = self.btnCancel.GetId())

        self.btnCancel = wx.Button(scroll2, label="Set All to "'Good'"", pos=(50,300))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, id = self.btnCancel.GetId())

        self.btnCancel = wx.Button(scroll2, label="Set All to "'Fair'"", pos=(50,350))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, id = self.btnCancel.GetId())

        self.btnCancel = wx.Button(scroll2, label="Set All to "'Poor'"", pos=(50,400))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, id = self.btnCancel.GetId())

        self.btnCancel = wx.Button(scroll2, label="Write LookUp Table to File", pos=(10,450))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose, id = self.btnCancel.GetId())
        scroll1.SetVirtualSize(scroll1.GetBestSize())

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Show(False)

    def Getvalues(self,event):
        r = 7 #row number
        c = 4 # number of columns in the grid
        texts = self.grid_sizer.GetChildren()[c*(r-1) : c*r - 1]  # returns a list of widgets inside the sizer
        for statictext in texts:
            if isinstance(statictext.GetWindow(), wx.StaticText):  # checks if it is a statictext
                statictext.GetWindow.SetLabel('data')              # sets the new data  

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'splitterwindow.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Do all the columns have static texts?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 4 columns in each row you can figure out that the `wx.staticTexts` in row 7 will be starting from 24th `wx.StaticText` object (starts from 0) to 27.

You can set the label of `StaticTexts` using something similar to the following:

```
r = #row number
c = 4 # number of columns in the grid
texts = gridsizer.GetChildren()[c*(r-1) : c*r - 1]  # returns a list of widgets inside the sizer
for statictext in texts:
    if isinstance(statictext.GetWindow(), wx.StaticText):  # checks if it is a statictext
        statictext.GetWindow.SetLabel('data')              # sets the new data
```

Some explanation [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/24/wxpython-how-to-get-children-widgets-from-a-sizer/).

Comment: I used same naming conventions `grid_sizer` as described in thread but got this error `NameError: global name 'grid_sizer' is not defined`

Comment: did you access the `grid_sizer` within the class?

Comment: ok. you need to make grid_sizer a class attribute by adding `self.` before it. otherwise it is out of scope of the even handler

Comment: I mean make all grid_sizer instances `self.` not just in the function.

Comment: 3rd line of your code gave:
`TypeError: in method 'SizerItemList___getitem__', expected argument 2 of type 'size_t'`

Comment: Could you post your code, it would be easier to find the problem.

Comment: can't really think of anything. You might want to post the entire/all codes, then I can run it on an IDE and debug.